# Q Google Calendar API Having 2 user credentials in my booking system

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am building a booking system for code clinics. Basically people volunteer there time to run a clinic on a topic and a person can book the slot.

What I need to do is store the data on the volunteers google calendar and on a code clinic calendar. The reason is  want to display all available clinics to my user and i would rather have all of them stored in one place.

How do I go about storing 2 sets of credentials for my requests. The first would be my users which i can have them always sign in with but the second would be the clinics calendar and i don't want to have my user have to sign in and authorise with the clinics calendar only there own.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `2 sets of credentials`? The credentials file you download from GCP is your *application's* credentials which you can use to authorise both the clinic and your user. You would need to build two `service` objects within your code though, one which accesses the user's Calendar and another which accesses the clinic calendar. Alternatively, you could use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) to perform actions on behalf of the clinic automatically so log-in authorisation doesn't have to be performed.

Comment: Can you provide more information or some code?